# Inverted Pulse Generator

Tags: transistors, inverting-amplifier

How to design a circuit (only using transistors) which takes  0V to 3.3V step at the input and generates a negative 1ms pulse at the output.

```
Input : ______|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾

Output: ‾‾‾‾‾‾|______|‾‾‾‾‾‾
                1 ms
```

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you already done? How do you think you should approach it?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't all pulse generators made up of transistors? Also, you tagged this question with "inverting amplifier". Are you using this for your assignment?

Comment: *two transistor schmitt trigger*. What remains is a high pass on the input.

Comment: This information is missing: Is this homework? (If yes, show your attempt, and we'll help you from there) - What should happen when *Input* goes from *H* to *L*? What should happen if *Input* goes from *H* to *L* and then *L* to *H* before 1 ms has elapsed? - What should happen if *Input* goes 0 to 3 V? Should it still switch? - Many other parameters missing, I don't expect you to provide all of this information. But as you can see, the devil is in the details.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments: Its not a home work, I was preparing for an interview and I found this is one of the typical questions they ask..I have lost touch with basic circuits and hence trying to solve few online questions   - Question says dont use logi gates, only use transistors - Question says its a step input so probably it will remain as such and the output should only be one inverting pulse that last for  1ms...

Comment: Janka  + Felthry : My initial thoughts were inverting Op Amp, but output I assume needs to be a pulse...Using a schmitt trigger you could trigger the output when the threshold is reached but it wont be a pulse if the input remains at the same level (step input)

Comment: Use a resistively-coupled flip-flop fed by a capacitor.  Take the output off of the first transistor.  Should be schematics on the web.  Be ready to explain how it acts as the charge on the cap decays, and over temperature.

Comment: @Nis Technically, logic gates are comprised of transistors ;) There are multiple ways you can approach this problem. You can look for a transistor circuit diagram of a 555 timer (which uses flip-flop topology), Schmitt triggering also works (this might be your easiest solution), some phase shifting could work.

Comment: @Nis Tim's idea of a capacitor is the first thing that crossed my mind. A differentiated rising edge forms a short upward spike. (The falling edge will form a short downward spike you can clip off with a diode and finish the job with a resistor when the diode drop is mostly exhausted.) You only need to respond to the upward spike, triggering a timer. That can be built with one BJT and one MOSFET (needed because the DC gate current is "zero"), allowing a simple RC to do some timing for you. Positive feedback as the RC depletes, will sharpen the ending edge for you.

Comment: Its called a monostable oscillator.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly direct solution.

[image]
The significant realisation is that this is a one-shot (monostable) oscillator, which is *edge*-triggered. To detect an edge, a series capacitor is the simplest method.

So the solution starts with a series capacitor. Next we want a 1ms delay. We already have a capacitor, so a resistive load will give us the delay we want. The signal then drives a transistor so we can drive the output.

`OUT1` is the signal we want, but it suffers from a slow rise time. The `OUT2` transistor sharpens it up for us, but is now inverted. So finally, `OUT3` inverts again and gives us the sharp, 1ms, inverted pulse we want.

Drawbacks of this approach are the reliance on the rise time and source impedance of the input signal. You'd need to know more about the situation to know whether these are issues or what to do about them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one topology that uses two transistors, two resistors and one capacitor. I'm aware that it goes against the "*only using transistors*" requirement, but I believe that resistors and capacitors are okay.

[image]

[link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.0000049999999999999996%2010.20027730826997%2062%203.3%2050%0Af%20432%20256%20480%20256%2032%201.5%200.2%0Af%20432%20208%20480%20208%2032%201.5%200.2%0Ac%20384%20208%20384%20256%200%200.000001%202.243125354741877%0Ar%20384%20304%20384%20256%200%202200%0Ag%20384%20304%20384%20320%200%0Aw%20384%20208%20432%20208%200%0Ar%20480%20144%20480%20192%200%201000%0AR%20480%20144%20480%20112%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0AM%20480%20192%20528%20192%200%202.5%0Aw%20480%20224%20480%20240%200%0Ag%20480%20272%20480%20320%200%0AR%20384%20208%20384%20176%201%202%20200%201.65%201.65%200%200.5%0A403%2096%20144%20352%20224%200%205_8_0_4106_5_6.4_0_2_5_3%0A403%20496%20208%20752%20288%200%208_8_0_4098_5_0.1_0_1%0Aw%20384%20256%20432%20256%200%0A403%2096%20224%20352%20304%200%2014_8_0_4354_5_0.8_0_2_14_3%0Ax%20538%20313%20698%20316%204%2024%201%5Csms%5Csdivision%0A) to simulation.

As you can see, It's just a simple [NAND gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) where one input is the high-pass filtered version of the other. And the oscilloscope output on the right shows that it indeed creates 1 ms pulses as the clock goes high.

If you'd want to make this circuit slightly better, then you should place a diode from ground to the bottom gate, this way the gate never goes below 0.7 V, and the circuit can oscillate even faster before the 1 ms pulses crashes into each other.

---

Now, time for a little bit of math, so during the interview they will say "ah, this guy knows what he's doing".

The threshold voltage of these NMOS in particular are 1.5 V, and for simplicity, let's assume that we are not driving the circuit at 200 Hz as I am. Let's assume we're driving it at maybe 1 Hz or some much longer time, meaning that the bottom left graph will start at 3.3 V and go down to 0 V, compared to 2.5 V.

The equation for the voltage of a discharging capacitor in a RC connection is:
$$
\large
V_c = V_E(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})
$$
And we want \$V_c\$ to be equal to 1.5 V after 1 ms. After some rewriting we get this equation:

$$
\large
RC=\dfrac{-t}{\ln\bigg(\frac{V_E-V_C}{V_E}\bigg)}
$$

So let's say we got a 1 µF laying around, that's realistic, and let's calculate R, the parameter that is by far easiest to change out of all parameters. So let's plug in our numbers and get R

$$
\large
R=\dfrac{-1\text{ ms}}{(1\text{ µF})\ln\bigg(\frac{3.3\text{ V}-1.5\text{ V}}{3.3\text{ V}}\bigg)}\approx1649\text{ Ω}
$$

Why am I not using 1649 Ω in the simulator? Because I made the gif before I made the equation and I am too lazy to update the gif. I did change the 2.2 kΩ to 1649 to verify that I'm on point, and yes, it looks like a 1 ms pulse as well.

---

Do I assume you to know the equation for the discharge of a capacitor in a RC circuit? 
Yes I do. It's very simple to derive, compared to other equations.